# How to forward optional arguments to a Git alias

Tags: git

I use `git commit --fixup=<commit>`frequently and want to shorten it to `git fixup <commit>`. Occasionally I want to add additional flags (e.g. `-a`). Therefore I have setup an alias which supports one additional flag (`$2`):

```
[alias]
  fixup = !sh -c 'git commit -m\"fixup! $1\" \"$2\"' -
```

Can this be generalized to support an arbitrary number of flags?

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this should work for you:

```
[alias]
  fixup = "!_() { local commit_id=\"$1\"; shift; git commit -m \"fixup! $commit_id\" \"$@\"; }; _"
```

It uses a shell function and the shift operator to peel off the first argument.  Then `$@` is available to use for the remaining arguments.